# Getting same value in all rows

Tags: postgresql

Can someone please tell me what wrong I am doing with the query.

```
select cr.name, count ( p.user_id) from profiles_profile p
inner join profiles_contact pc on p.contact_id = pc.id
inner join location_address la on pc.address_id = la.id 
inner join cities_country cc on la.country_id = cc.id
inner join cities_region cr on cc.id = cr.country_id
where p.approve_status = 'approved'
and p.user_class = 'user'
and cc."name" like 'Germany'
group by cr.name
```

Please find the screen shot with the output of this query.
[image]

Comment: use a count(*)  - just a hunch, without DDL and Data its difficult to see

Comment: Tried with count(*) too, same result.

Comment: I'am just guessing: replace `inner join cities_region cr on cc.id = cr.country_id` with `inner join cities_region cr on cr.id = cc.country_id`